# paste command puts data from csv files vertically line by line instead of horizontally next to each other

Tags: command-line, zsh, paste

I have a few csv-s, each containing 3 columns separated by ",".
Example:

```
header1,header2,header3
value1,value2,value3
value1,value2,value3
...
```

Using [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/paste-command-in-linux-with-examples/), I thought if I execute `paste -d "," *csv > output.csv` I will end up with something like this:

```
header1,header2,header3,header1,header2,header3,...
value1,value2,value3,value1,value2,value3,...
value1,value2,value3,value1,value2,value3,...
```

but instead the output looks like this:

```
header1,header2,header3,
header1,header2,header3,
header1,header2,header3,
...
value1,value2,value3,
value1,value2,value3,
...
```

especially each line is 3 columns wide, instead of the number of csv files * 3 wide.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Was the any of the files by any chance edited on a Windows system? If so, try running `dos2unix` over them before processing.

Comment: No, they were created on a Unix machine.

Comment: Strange. If I try the command you posted, with the example data you show, I actually get the desired result (I tried with 3 CSV files). So your approach looks valid, there must be something else with the files themselves.

Comment: There's technically nothing stopping a Unix program from creating CSV files in DOS text format. I would suggest running the files through `dos2unix` regardless of the origin of the files.

Comment: @Kusalananda Fun fact: I tested it with CSV files that I converted to Windows line endings using `unix2dos`, but the `paste` result didn't look like the unwanted output the OP got ... chances are there is still something else missing.

Comment: @AdminBee Not so fun as interesting.  I can reproduce the issue with files in Mac text format, when interpreted on a system that expect DOS text... I think. So there's definitely something up with the EOL markers.

Comment: @Kusalananda Wow, can it even get more confusing? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your original files have `\r\n` end of lines.

If it is so, the final file would have an extra `\r` between each line segment. Try using `tr`:

```
paste -d "," *csv | tr -d "\r" > output.csv
```

Comment: Careful, `tr` and `paste` will be started at the same time, if `output.csv` is opened before the `*csv` glob is expanded, you may end up in an infinite loop that fills up the disk.